# Hazelcast event consistency

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using hazelcast local listener for my use case. i have read the documentation and understands that it uses queue to push events to listeners.

What happens to the events in the queue of node that is down ? will these be ignored or will be in queue and routed to new node if the replica is configured ? Please clarify.

Is there any way to acknowledge the successful receive of the message with some kind of call back ? so that event never be lost.

Answer (score 0):

LocalListener queues are not distributed (as it would involve serialization). Anyhow listeners are not expected to do long running operations therefore your queue should always be empty. Queues tend to have only one of two states: empty or full (depending on fast or slow consumer).

And yes if the node goes down and your local queue is full, you'll loose events.

What is your usecase? Do you have slow consumers? Think to offload them to a Hazelcast distributed queue and execute them independently from the event threads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. my listener just publish the message into vertx event bus. Thats all. i dont think it is long running operations.

Comment: i am building auto push incident system. all open incidents will be loaded into hazelcast memeory. any updates/additions to incidents should be automatically pushed to logged in user(UI).